# variable value causing error: IR generation failure program too clever

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the simple code that causing problem:

```
class CoreViewController: UIViewController {
    private let isPad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad
}
```

Following is the erorr message

> <unknown>:0: error: IR generation failure: program too clever: variable collides with existing symbol OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice

No error, if I remove `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` will **NOT** work in Swift, it's an Objective-C macro.

#### Solution

**Option 1.**  Use `UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom` instead.

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .Phone:
        // It's an iPhone
    case .Pad:
        // It's an iPad
    case .Unspecified:
        // Undefined
    }
```

**Option 2.** Request an `UITraitCollection` instance and check the idiom (recommended)

```
let deviceIdiom = UIScreen.mainScreen().traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom

switch (deviceIdiom) {

case .Pad:
        // It's an iPad
case .Phone:
        // It's an iPhone
case .TV: 
        // Apple TV
default:
        // Undefined    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is a macro. It might not work from Swift.